# 絵文字が分かれるときがある

Tags: unicode

絵文字を入力していると、分かれるとき（2文字に分解される）ときとされないときがあります。

使っているWebサービスやアプリに依存していると思うのですが、どういった仕組みでわかれてしまうのでしょうか？

今たまたまSublimte Textで試してみたところ添付画像のようにエディタ内は1文字の絵文字でしたが、タイトル部分（ファイル名？）部分は2文字に分裂しておりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

単純に分割してしまう理由が知りたいです。

文字列判定（たとえばシンプルに文字列判定(if文）や正規表現）を使うときやデータベースへの保存時になにか問題が起こるのではないかという漠然とした不安を取り除きたいという理由でも質問しております。

Comment: この辺の記事 [絵文字の連結と、書記素クラスター判定](https://ufcpp.net/blog/2017/10/graphemesplitter/), [親方！空から絵文字が！](https://virtualcast.jp/blog/2019/10/emoji/), [Unicode 絵文字にまつわるあれこれ (絵文字の標準とプログラム上でのハンドリング)](https://qiita.com/_sobataro/items/47989ee4b573e0c2adfc) で説明されている、元となっているであろう [Unicode® Standard Annex #29 UNICODE TEXT SEGMENTATION](https://ufcpp.net/blog/2017/10/graphemesplitter/) を、それぞれのコンポーネントでのサポート有無とかサポートしていてもどんな解釈・仕様で実装されているか、にかかっているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: もしかしたらサロゲートペアの文字かもしれませんね。C#だとサロゲートペアの文字は１文字でも長さ２として処理されます。https://codezine.jp/article/detail/1592

Answer (score 1):

ファイルシステムにAppleのHFS+を利用していませんか?
AppleのHFS+はNFDと呼ばれる、合字を各素片毎に分割して連続記述する仕組みになっています。（たとえば、プと書いても、ファイルシステム上はフ（U+30D5)＋゜(U+309a)と2文字に分かたれて記述されています。
NFDの反対はNFCと呼ばれ、プは1文字（U+3D07)で表現されます。
質問の事項はその絵文字版合字が分割されて記述されているのだと思います。
もし、上記であればAppleのファイルシステム上の問題で、ファイル内部は、NFC, NFDはファイル制作者の意図したとおりに（基本的にはNFCで)記述されているので比較が等価にならないなどの問題は起きないはずです。